# tar - How to preserve timestamps down to more than a second of precision?

Tags: tar, timestamps, archive

I am using `tar` to package a number of files. Modify timestamps on the files are critical, and must be of high accuracy. Using `tar -cvf`, timestamps are preserved but rounded to the nearest second, i.e. running `stat` on the files displays only timestamps that end in .0. Is there a way to preserve timestamps to greater accuracy, or is there a different archive tool I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The usual `tar` format stores timestamps as a number of seconds, as you determined. To store timestamps with more resolution, you need to use another format, such as POSIX `tar` as produced by GNU `tar` which stores timestamps in nanoseconds (usually).

To create these archives, use the `-H posix` option with GNU `tar`:

```
tar cfH archive.tar posix ...
```